# GoogleCode: can I host css an js files for my site for free on google code hosting?

Tags: google-code

I saw on jQuery UI site such line in source code:

```
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Looks like they host there static files on google servers to save their server resources.

It's very interesting. I haven't found usefull descriptions from [googlecode.com](http://googlecode.com).

So, is it possible for me to do the same with my site static files fo free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just upload your files to [a Google Code repository](http://code.google.com/hosting/) and you'll be able to find a direct link to the raw files.

Comment: So it means yes? And could anyone except me delete them from there?

Comment: Only users with commit access to the repository would be able to make any changes.

Comment: As the project owner, yes, you can [control other owners, committers, and contributors using the admin interface](http://i.imgur.com/whjNJ.png). Perhaps you should just peruse the docs: http://code.google.com/p/support/